# "They" to refer to a person's looks?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

If you say *"her looks have faded"* would you say in response, *"No, **they** haven't"* or is that ***"they"*** incorrect?

Comment: I'm guessing you're asking because you're not sure if "looks" should be treated as a singular noun. In future questions, you might want to elaborate a bit more on **why** you're confused.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since the *subject* is "**looks**" and it's *plural*, **they** is correct. Hence, your response, "**No they haven't.**" is correct.